# Trouble displaying a bitmap in a custom view using canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, face-detection

Im attempting to write an android app which allows you to select an image from the gallery, via an intent, which will then be analysed by FaceDetector and displayed with in the same view. However I'm having trouble just displaying the image thus far. Can anyone help?? Thanks in advance

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Image"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/targeturi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <view
        class="com.example.facedetectionstaticcamera.myView"
        android:id="@+id/analysedimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.facedetectionstaticcamera;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
TextView textTargetUri;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

       Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);
       textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);

       buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
       startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    });    
    }  


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
        BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
    BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri), null, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        myView newView = new myView(this, null);
            myView.setBitmap(bitmap);
            v.addView(newView);
            bitmap.recycle();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
    }
    }
```

myView

```
     package com.example.facedetectionstaticcamera;

     import java.io.File;
     import com.example.facedetectionstaticcamera.R;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
     import android.graphics.Canvas;
     import android.graphics.Color;
     import android.graphics.Paint;
     import android.graphics.PointF;
     import android.media.FaceDetector;
     import android.media.FaceDetector.Face;
     import android.os.Environment;
     import android.util.AttributeSet;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.ImageView;


    public class myView extends View{

static Bitmap myBitmap;


public static void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    myBitmap = bitmap;

}

public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}
@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null); 
}
}
```

Comment: Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about REMOVING the line:

```
 bitmap.recycle();
```

According to android developer:

Caution: You should use recycle() only when you are sure that the bitmap is no longer being used. If you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap".

You'd better let the GC to do it for you.

> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: If i do not delete the old bitmap i will run out of memory.

Comment: But i have already copied the original bitmap to mybitmap when i call the setBitmap method. Therefore i don't believe I need to orginal bitmap. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: java will pass the object parameter as reference, it it not copied.

Comment: Okay. I've removed bitmap.recycle(). I'll address the memory issue later. But I still don't get an image displayed. On logcat i'm getting 07-22 13:17:15.500: E/Bitmap_JNI(10698): Failed to create SkBitmap buffer!

Answer (score 0):

Pls can you try adding invalidate() call:

```
public static void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
 myBitmap = bitmap;
 this.invalidate();
}
```